# .Net c# Error with Json : Error Converting Value

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core

I can't seem to be bale to convert Json to my desired List class.

I got the Json file and passed it to [Json to C#](https://json2csharp.com/)

and it generated the class:

```
    public class Customers
{
    [JsonProperty("Customers")]
    public string Oid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Customers")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Customers")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Customers")]
    public string Kwdikos { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Customers")]
    public string AFM { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Customers")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Customers")]
    public string DOY { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Customers")]
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Customers")]
    public int FPA { get; set; }

}

public class CustomersList
 {
     [JsonProperty("Customers")]
    public List<Customers> _customersList { get; set; }
 }
```

and I am using the code to get the Json to my List Class like this:

```
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomersList>>(content, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                });
```

But I get an error saying:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerliazitaionException : 'Error converting value
> "(My Json file)" to type

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DemoProject6.CustomersList]'. Path
> '', line 1, position 37574.'

Any Idea on how to solve this? Thank you for your time !!!

Comment: what is the value of the content variable?

Comment: @SenAlexandru the value is the Json response from Get method that I used.

Comment: I'm afraid we can't answer this question as we don't know the value of `content`. We understand what `content` is, but we don't know what the value is. Because of this, we can only speculate at what might be wrong (the problem is 100% dependent on _your JSON_).

Comment: @John just changed the tag, I understand I can copy paste the content but is big. But as I used the json2csharp web page we get an Idea of what the content looks like.

Comment: We'd _probably_ only need to see one item of the property `Customers`, so you wouldn't need to include every item, so long as you provide well formed JSON that matches the structure of the original. You should also probably anonymise any data.

Comment: @AlexRika understand that debugging won't work on assumptions. The first step in debugging your scenario is to see if the JSON has a valid format, just as John is suggesting

Comment: @John okay let me show you the content

Comment: @SenAlexandru I will show some conent second

Comment: My wild guess is that your JSON isn't `[{ "customersList": [{ ... }, { ... }] }, { "customersList": [{ ... }] }]` but `{ "customersList": [{ ... ], { ... }} }`, and that you shouldn't be deserializing a list of `CustomersList`, but without seeing your JSON I can't possibly be sure, it would just seem to make the most sense.

Comment: Try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomersList>(content)`

Comment: Try to format your json and check which line causes an error

Comment: @John yes it is like that: "[{"Oid":"cea01abc-f96e-4adb-b6c4-0130d9f641de","Name":. and so on...

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski format where?

Comment: @Vernou still same problem...

Comment: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Show your JSON. We've given it our best guess, but without seeing your actual JSON, we can't help you. We're programmers, not psychics. Edit your question. Include your JSON. Then we can help.

Comment: @John okay I will include now it contains Properties in greek ( I  dont think is a problem right)

Comment: Nope, no problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219942/discussion-between-alex-rika-and-john).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JsonPropertyAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) specified for the property, the name in JSON texte. But in your example, all properties have `[JsonProperty("Customers")]`. The JSON generated by your model will be :

```
{
  "Customer": [{
    "Customers": "Oid value",
    "Customers": "Name value",
    "Customers": "Title value",
    ...
  }]
}
```

In JSON, you can't have by level some property with the same name.

By default, the json property's name is class property's name.
Solution :

```cs
public class Customers
{
    public string Oid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Kwdikos { get; set; }
    public string AFM { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string DOY { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    public int FPA { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```cs
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customers>>(content);
```

edit:
I think the response's content isn't well formatted.
Maybe you can try :

```cs
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var customersJson = Regex.Unescape(content.Substring(1, content.Length - 2));
var customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customers>>(customersJson);
```

Comment: Try `var content = Regex.Unescape(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());`

Comment: Trying right now. I just want tell you that my response json contains backslashes / before each quotes property is that something that might be leading to errors?

Comment: Yep I tried and launcher keeps stopping when I try it. So the above line of code didn't work

Comment: @Alex Rida, yes, backslashes before each quotes isn't valid json. This explain why https://json2csharp.com/ give you a bad model classes. See my edit to get a valid json.